# Spring webflux controller: consuming POJO vs Mono?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller, project-reactor

In a controller I can write:

```
fun update(@RequestBody myPojo: MyPojo): Mono<Void>
```

or

```
fun update(@RequestBody myPojo: Mono<MyPojo>): Mono<Void>
```

is there any difference? will the body parsing be done in different threads? in first case will i block the main reactor thread until `myPojo` is parsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no strong runtime difference between the two; in the first case, Spring will unwrap the incoming `Mono`, but the decoding will still happen asynchronously.

The only difference is that without a `Mono` type as an argument, you won't be able to use Reactor operators on it. So this is really about what needs to be achieved in your controller handler.